# ffmpeg in not working in php exec()

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

FFMPEG is not working in exec but its working when using ssh on that us
but other commands work with exec !

Here is the code :

```
exec("ffmpeg -i /home/setare/public_html/kanalmanager/wt/230307754.mp4 -i /home/setare/public_html/kanalmanager/wt/230307754_logo.png \
 -filter_complex  "[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=1,scale=iw*1.4:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2" /home/setare/public_html/kanalmanager/wt/230307754_send.mp4 -y");
```

Comment: Syntax error, unescaped quotes

Comment: Either escape the inner quotes, or use single quotes around the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charlotte Dunois said you have syntax error, and this one should works:

```
exec("ffmpeg -i /home/setare/public_html/kanalmanager/wt/230307754.mp4 -i /home/setare/public_html/kanalmanager/wt/230307754_logo.png \
 -filter_complex  \"[1]colorchannelmixer=aa=1,scale=iw*1.4:-1[wm];[0][wm]overlay=x=(W-w)/2:y=(H-h)/2\" /home/setare/public_html/kanalmanager/wt/230307754_send.mp4 -y");
```